# Using views in drupal simplenews

Tags: drupal-6

I am using Drupal 6.x and Simplenews to send newsletters. I want to build the mailing list using email address field of student content type. Is there a way to use views to get email address of all the students in the system to send newsletters to them?

Comment: Tip: Now there is http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

sure you can get all e-mails of students go to "Administrator section - views"

1- Add a new view and give it name "for example : test" .

2- You'll then find a section called filter "press on it and add node type equal to student content types".

3- In Fields section choose the "email field for student".

4- don't forget to make "Items to display" at Basic settings section to be unlimited .

To check the view results you'll find at the end a live preview to check the results.

In order to get the view result

```
$view = views_get_view('test'); // where test is the view name
$view->set_display('default'); // in case it's page "page-0" in case block "block-0"
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$result = $view->result;
```

the second part it to take this result and make a custom module to send to these students the news letter .

Comment: Thanks but what to write in that custom module to subscribe these students to a newsletter having title e.g. "Test Newsletter"?

Comment: have a look to these links 1- http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/6  2-http://www.trevorsimonton.com/blog/drupalmail-example-tutorial-explanation . you'll find a drupal_mail function you can use it .